# Swift not activating stylistic alternatives for label

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

I'm trying to enable stylistic alternatives for otf font pluto-sans however no matter what I do the default set is all that it uses.

When i look at the font attributes in xcode debugging i get the following

```
(
        {
        CTFeatureTypeIdentifier = 0;
        CTFeatureTypeName = "All Typographic Features";
        CTFeatureTypeNameID = "-100";
        CTFeatureTypeSelectors =         (
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorDefault = 1;
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 0;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = On;
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-101";
            }
        );
    },
        {
        CTFeatureTypeExclusive = 1;
        CTFeatureTypeIdentifier = 6;
        CTFeatureTypeName = "Number Spacing";
        CTFeatureTypeNameID = "-700";
        CTFeatureTypeSelectors =         (
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 0;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = "Monospaced Numbers";
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-701";
            },
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorDefault = 1;
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 4;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = "No Change";
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-705";
            }
        );
    },
        {
        CTFeatureTypeExclusive = 1;
        CTFeatureTypeIdentifier = 10;
        CTFeatureTypeName = "Vertical Position";
        CTFeatureTypeNameID = "-1100";
        CTFeatureTypeSelectors =         (
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorDefault = 1;
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 0;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = "Normal Vertical Position";
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-1101";
            },
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 1;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = "Superiors/Superscripts";
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-1102";
            },
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 3;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = Ordinals;
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-1104";
            },
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 4;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = "Scientific Inferiors";
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-1105";
            }
        );
    },
        {
        CTFeatureTypeIdentifier = 11;
        CTFeatureTypeName = "Contextual Fractional Forms";
        CTFeatureTypeNameID = "-1200";
        CTFeatureTypeSelectors =         (
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 2;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = On;
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-1203";
            }
        );
    },
        {
        CTFeatureTypeExclusive = 1;
        CTFeatureTypeIdentifier = 17;
        CTFeatureTypeName = Alternates;
        CTFeatureTypeNameID = "-1800";
        CTFeatureTypeSelectors =         (
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorDefault = 1;
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 0;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = "No Alternates";
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-1801";
            },
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 1;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = "Alternate 1";
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-1802";
            },
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 2;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = "Alternate 2";
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-1803";
            },
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 3;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = "Alternate 3";
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-1804";
            },
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 4;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = "Alternate 4";
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-1805";
            },
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 5;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = "Alternate 5";
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-1806";
            }
        );
    },
        {
        CTFeatureTypeExclusive = 1;
        CTFeatureTypeIdentifier = 21;
        CTFeatureTypeName = "Number Case";
        CTFeatureTypeNameID = "-2200";
        CTFeatureTypeSelectors =         (
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 1;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = "Lining Figures";
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-2202";
            },
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorDefault = 1;
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 2;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = "No Change";
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-2203";
            }
        );
    },
        {
        CTFeatureTypeExclusive = 1;
        CTFeatureTypeIdentifier = 22;
        CTFeatureTypeName = "Text Spacing";
        CTFeatureTypeNameID = "-2300";
        CTFeatureTypeSelectors =         (
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorDefault = 1;
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 7;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = "No Change";
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-2308";
            },
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 8;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = "No Kerning";
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-2309";
            }
        );
    },
        {
        CTFeatureTypeIdentifier = 33;
        CTFeatureTypeName = "Case-Sensitive Layout";
        CTFeatureTypeNameID = "-3400";
        CTFeatureTypeSelectors =         (
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 0;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = "Capital Forms";
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-3401";
            },
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 2;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = "Capital Spacing";
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-3403";
            }
        );
    },
        {
        CTFeatureTypeIdentifier = 35;
        CTFeatureTypeName = "Alternative Stylistic Sets";
        CTFeatureTypeNameID = "-3600";
        CTFeatureTypeSelectors =         (
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 2;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = "Stylistic Set 1";
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-3603";
            },
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 4;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = "Stylistic Set 2";
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-3605";
            },
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 6;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = "Stylistic Set 3";
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-3607";
            }
        );
    },
        {
        CTFeatureTypeIdentifier = 36;
        CTFeatureTypeName = "Contextual Alternates";
        CTFeatureTypeNameID = "-3700";
        CTFeatureTypeSelectors =         (
                        {
                CTFeatureSelectorDefault = 1;
                CTFeatureSelectorIdentifier = 0;
                CTFeatureSelectorName = "Contextual Alternates";
                CTFeatureSelectorNameID = "-3701";
            }
        );
    }
)
```

The above was printed out with the following code:

```
    var a = CTFontCopyFeatures(label.font)
    println(a)
```

I'm trying to activate the stylistic alternatives with the following code:

```
var newfont = UIFontDescriptor(name: "Pluto Sans Cond Medium", size: CGFloat(0.0))

label.font = UIFont(descriptor:        newfont.fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes([UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: kStylisticAlternativesType, UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey: kStylisticAltOneOnSelector]), size: CGFloat(17))
```

I'm fairly new to swift and fonts but as far as i can tell this should activate the stylistic alternatives, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This blog post lead me to a solution: http://generic.cx/essays/font-descriptors/ I ended up extending uifont like so:

```
extension UIFont {
    func activateAlternatives() -> UIFont {
        let oDesc = self.fontDescriptor()
        let features: [NSObject: AnyObject] = [
            UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute: [
                [
                    UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey:
                    kStylisticAlternativesType,
                    UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey:
                    kStylisticAltOneOnSelector
                ]
                ,[
                    UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey:
                    kStylisticAlternativesType,
                    UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey:
                    kStylisticAltTwoOnSelector
                ],
                [
                    UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey:
                    kStylisticAlternativesType,
                    UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey:
                    kStylisticAltThreeOnSelector
                ]
            ]
        ]
        let newDesc = oDesc.fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes(features)
        return UIFont(descriptor: newDesc, size: 0.0)
    }
}
```

I think my problem wasn't actually that the code was wrong, but that i needed to use all three alternatives to get all the glyphs I was expecting